# How to study the source code of my favorite program?

Tags: language-agnostic

I've downloaded the source code of my favourite program.

At school they taught us that the entry point is the main.c(pp) and then follow the headers, but I realise that is not always the case. In some cases there isn't a main or It deep buried somewhere where I can find it.

And the documentation in most cases describes only how to compile, what deps you need and etc.

Bottom line, you've downloaded the code, untar'ed it.. now what?

I don't have any particular example to ask (help) for, so if you have any example to help me it's welcome

Comment: excuse me for the lack of appropriate tags ,I know it's pretty generic

Comment: step one - run it in a debugger to get a feel for the program flow

Comment: What language in particular is your program written in?

Answer (score 4):

Reading code is often more cumbersome than writing code. This inquiry does not have a single answer and you should explore multiple opinions and see which works best for you. One practice you shouldn't engage in is reading the code start to finish. This will lead to eye bleeding and mind-numbing frustration. So don't approach it like a book, since reading it like one, cover to cover, is very inefficient. Reading is **not** learning. Applying what you read is learning. One key point to remember is *don't get discouraged*. You will be hard pressed to find a programmer that can quickly pick up on a foreign, large base of code quickly.

- The best 'book speed readers' skim through something they are about to read a form an outline in their head. They take mental notes of logical sections and paint a thin picture about what to expect. When your brain has seen something before, it is more likely to be engaged with the material. I would skim the header files as a way to form this outline. If there are no header files, then try to skim quickly though class interfaces and take note of which are connected and what is their general purpose.
- Make a second pass through the sections of code that interested you. Try to identify a subsystem of the code and make a second, more detailed pass through it. I personally would look for connected components for identifying the subsystems (look at imports). Jot down some of the data structures used and associated algorithms and design patterns. Make associations between them and try to understand why they were used.
- Lastly, don't be content with just reading the code. Since you are looking at open source, challenge yourself to add a feature. Take one of the subsystems you were intrigued with and add on to it. If this still intimidates you, take the last bullet a step further. Make a quick flow chart detailing the flow of the code. Bust out your favorite IDE and leverage breakpoints around areas you don't understand the flow. Try to put yourself in the mind of the designer and think why he made certain decisions as your stepping through the breakpoints. Bottom line: It is easy read something and think you understand it. But, *doing* is where the real learning takes place. You will find yourself asking more questions and researching more into the code when adding a new feature. Having this direction is all it takes sometimes.

If the source code leverages an OOP solution, I would strongly recommend studying a Design Patterns book. I was going to include Design Patterns as a bullet, but I didn't know if the source code you are viewing uses an OOP approach.

Hope this helps! This was the approach I undertook when learning to code a couple years ago.